Magento 2 How to Get Bundle product options lables with value in custom email templates
how do I get bundle product options labels with value in my custom email templates?
My custom email template code is here..
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// phpcs:disable Magento2.Templates.ThisInTemplate

/** @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items */
?>
<?php $_order = $block->getOrder() ?>
<?php $_imageHelper = $this->helper(\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image::class); ?>
<?php if ($_order) : ?>
    <?php $_items = $_order->getAllVisibleItems(); ?>
    <table class="email-items">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                </th>
                <th class="item-info">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Product')) ?>
                </th>
                <th class="item-info">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('SKU')) ?>
                </th>
                <th class="item-info">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($_items as $_item) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php if($_item->getProduct()): ?>
                    <img src="<?= $_imageHelper->init($_item->getProduct(), 'small_image', ['type'=>'small_image'])->keepAspectRatio(true)->resize('120','120')->getUrl();?>" alt="<?= __('Product Image');?>">
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="product-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="product-sku"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getSku()) ?></p>
                </td>
                <td class="item-qty">
                    <?= (float) $_item->getQtyOrdered() ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>

Layout code is here..
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Order Items List" design_abstraction="custom">
    <update handle="sales_email_order_renderers"/>
    <update handle="sales_email_item_price"/>
    <body>
        <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items" name="items" template="Vendor_Extension::order/email/items.phtml" cacheable="false">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="sales.email.order.renderers" as="renderer.list"/>
            <block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals" name="order_totals" template="Magento_Sales::order/totals.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label_properties" xsi:type="string">colspan="2"</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Tax\Block\Sales\Order\Tax" name="tax" template="Magento_Tax::order/tax.phtml">
                    <action method="setIsPlaneMode">
                        <argument name="value" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                    </action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </block>
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="additional.product.info" template="Magento_Theme::template.phtml"/>
    </body>
</page>


@Keval Chauhan
Hey,

Create a custom block to fetch bundle product options.

Use the Block in Email Template
{{block class="YourVendor\YourModule\Block\BundleOptions" product_id=$product.id template="YourVendor_YourModule::bundle_options.phtml"}}

Create the Template File
 getBundleOptions($block->getData('product_id'));
 ?>
 
 <ul>
     <?php foreach ($options as $option): ?>
         <li>
             <strong><?php echo $option['label']; ?>:</strong>
             <ul>
                 <?php foreach ($option['values'] as $value): ?>
                     <li><?php echo $value; ?></li>
                 <?php endforeach; ?>
             </ul>
         </li>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
 </ul>



Thank You!

I found my own solution And this solution works like a charm!!..
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// phpcs:disable Magento2.Templates.ThisInTemplate

/** @var $block \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items */
?>
<?php $_order = $block->getOrder() ?>
<?php $_imageHelper = $this->helper(\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image::class); ?>
<?php if ($_order) : ?>
    <?php $_items = $_order->getAllVisibleItems(); ?>
    <table class="email-items">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                </th>
                <th class="item-info">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Product')) ?>
                </th>
                <th class="item-info">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('SKU')) ?>
                </th>
                <th class="item-info">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($_items as $_item) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php if ($_item->getProduct()): ?>
                    <img src="<?= $_imageHelper->init($_item->getProduct(), 'small_image', ['type'=>'small_image'])->keepAspectRatio(true)->resize('120','120')->getUrl();?>" alt="<?= __('Product Image');?>">
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="product-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></p>
                    <?php
                    $productType = $_item->getProductType();
                    $options = $_item->getProductOptions();
                    
                    // Display configurable product options
                    if ($productType == \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE && isset($options['attributes_info'])): ?>
                        <ul>
                            <?php foreach ($options['attributes_info'] as $attribute): ?>
                                <li><strong><?= $block->escapeHtml($attribute['label']) ?>:</strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($attribute['value']) ?></li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($productType == \Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_CODE && isset($options['bundle_options'])): ?>
                        <ul>
                            <?php foreach ($options['bundle_options'] as $bundleOption): ?>
                                <li><strong><?= $block->escapeHtml($bundleOption['label']) ?>:</strong>
                                    <ul>
                                        <?php foreach ($bundleOption['value'] as $bundleItem): ?>
                                            <li><?= $block->escapeHtml($bundleItem['title']) ?> <strong>QTY:</strong>  <?= (float)$bundleItem['qty'] ?></li>
                                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="product-sku"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getSku()) ?></p>
                </td>
                <td class="item-qty">
                    <?= (float) $_item->getQtyOrdered() ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>

